# Is there an "on event" for downloads?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, error-handling

I wonder if anyone knows this one.

I was getting a pretty tough error on my asp.net vb web app. I tell you I nearly had qwerty emblazened on my forehead for bangin my head against the keyboard. But I think I figured out the cause of the error:

I have the following code:

```
 fileToDownload = createFileSet(fileToDownload, confirm)
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent()
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileToDownload.Name)
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileToDownload.Length.ToString())
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = ReturnExtension(fileToDownload.Extension.ToLower())
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(fileToDownload.FullName)
                    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
                    Directory.Delete("C:\temp_" & confirm, True)
                    'System.IO.File.Delete(fileToDownload.FullName) <--- Error here
```

When I take the comment tick off that last line I get a real ugly error (I could redo it and spell it out, what kind of error, but it really doesn't matter).

I think I know the cause. The user is downloading a file, or in process of, or something, and the program is attempting to delete it... causing the error.

Is there a way of creating some `on HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile.complete` (code made up) or am I resorted to a batch file and a windows scheduler to clean up these files that are no longer needed?

Is my error conclusion correct, you think? I really don't see a way of creating an "on event" but I'm too new at asp.net to know for sure.

Comment: If you are deleting the directory the file is in (C:\temp_xxx) then attempting to delete the file will fail... ??

Comment: naw... that's too simple :). I could have been more clear, in another part of the code I'm creating a zip file out of that directory... I don't need either one when all is said and done. So I delete the directory (successfully) and then I need to delete the zip that was created out of that directory.

Comment: Just a comment - it is *always* a good idea to include the error details. Saying "I had some sort of error but I don't remember exactly what it was and it doesn't matter" not only ensures that you'll waste time fixing the wrong error, it's also disrespectful of the time others will waste trying to help you with insufficient information.

Comment: Well, in this case I really think the error is a waste of time, but I certainly don't want to be disrespectful... so here it is: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The handle is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070006 (E_HANDLE))
--- see? ugly, huh! :)

Comment: but, I suppose it does illustrate how I came to the conclusion I came to

Comment: You could read the zip file contents into a memory stream, delete the file then push the memory stream out to the response buffer. Only issue I can see with that is if the download fails and they want to try and get it again. Anyway heres a post showing you how to deal with files and memory streams and pushing it out to the response buffer http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/jhblankenship/DownloadingFromMemStream11262005060834AM/DownloadingFromMemStream.aspx

Comment: @bUKaneer Thank you! that's the direction I was looking for. FYI, the whole reason for creating the zip file is because inside there is a unique confirmation code. So, download again, is not an option. This may be just the solution I was looking for. If you'll pop it into an actual answer I'll accept it.

Comment: No worries have posted comment as answer and added an alternative - always more than one way to skin a rabbit ;o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a finally block (got the idea from here http://forums.asp.net/t/1436818.aspx/1 ). Inshort do this...

```
try {
 fileToDownload = createFileSet(fileToDownload, confirm)
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent()
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileToDownload.Name)
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileToDownload.Length.ToString())
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = ReturnExtension(fileToDownload.Extension.ToLower())
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(fileToDownload.FullName)
                    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
                    Directory.Delete("C:\temp_" & confirm, True)
} finally {
    System.IO.File.Delete(fileToDownload.FullName)
}
```

Or do this:

You could read the zip file contents into a memory stream, delete the file then push the memory stream out to the response buffer. Only issue I can see with that is if the download fails and they want to try and get it again. Anyway heres a post showing you how to deal with files and memory streams and pushing it out to the response buffer http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/jhblankenship/DownloadingFromMemStream11262005060834AM/DownloadingFromMemStream.aspx